# PHP For loop with complex input array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, form-post

Okay, I need some help here. I have a form where the user can add/remove some input fields. Those fields live in modals that are dynamically built using jQuery. This is my basic setup:

```
<!--The fields I'm building and capturing-->
<script>
...
  var fieldOne = '<input type="text" name="field'+groupCount+'[one]">';
  var fieldTwo = '<input type="text" name="field'+groupCount+'[two]">';
...
</script>
```

groupCount is set by incremental button clicks. If groupCount is zero, no fields exist. This results in a series of **field1[one]**, **field1[two]**, **field2[one]**, **field2[two]**, and so on.

The form these live in will (of course) post to a separate PHP file. I know I can assign PHP variables to each individual field, but that doesn't help for larger groups.

I assume I would use some sort of *for loop* to capture these field values, but don't have the slightest clue how. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use Multi-Dimensions also from HTML... `name="field[1][one]"`

Comment: How would that help me with the PHP side? Would I use something like:
```for($i=0;$i<$groupCount;$i++){$field[$i]one = $_POST['field'.$i.['one']];}```

Comment: Well... sort of. But you need to make yourself familiar with PHP arrays and how to use them properly. Your example code won't run.

Answer (score 0):

in your php you can use preg_match

```php
$data = array();
foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
    $matches = array();
    if (preg_match('/^field(\d+)$/', $key, $matches)) {
        $data[$matches[1]][] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($data);
```